# How to upgrade Windows 10 to version 1703 instead of 1709?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1703

**How** do I upgrade a VM copy of Windows 10 to version 1703 (Redstone 2 - Creators Update) instead of to version 1709 (Redstone 3 - Fall Creators Update)? I have not been able to find the redistributable update and the update tools explicitly want to upgrade to the latest version. As a developer I *can not* skip a version here for testing purposes.

This is *explicitly not* an if/should question; those are reserved for noobs who lack a decisive reason for their questions.

Comment: Just download the current 1703 ISO, mount the ISO within Windows, and launch setup.exe..

Comment: @Ramhound Linkage please?

Comment: There are existing answers with direct links.  Otherwise, you can download the ISO, directly from Microsoft

Comment: http://windowsiso.net/windows-10-iso/windows-10-creators-update-1703-download-build-15063/

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths MSDN links don't work but the others (when you can *see* them) do. Edge 14 wasn't displaying the second column for some reason.